# Rspec: Test initialize method calls another method and returns a value

Tags: ruby, rspec, initialization, return

I want to test that;

1) a class calls a particular method within its initialize method

2) that method returns a particular value.

My Code:

```
it 'should call message method with a message' do
  expect_any_instance_of(MyExample).to receive(:message).with("A Message")
  MyExample.new("A Message")
end

it 'should call message method with a message and return message_var in reverse' do
  expect_any_instance_of(MyExample).to receive(:message).with("A Message").and_return("this should fail")
  MyExample.new("A Message")
end



class MyExample
  def initialize(m)
    message(m)
  end

  def message(m)
    return m.reverse
   end
 end
```

The problem is the second test always passes, whatever is passed to .and_return()

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!
Full code listing: http://pastebin.com/pkNuZfC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`and_return` is not part of the expectation, it is part of the stub - instead of actually calling the expected method, it simply returns the parameter passed to `and_return`.

To check the return value of the message, you need to call it and expect its value:

```
it 'returns message_var in reverse' do
  example = MyExample.new("A Message")

  expect(example.message("A message")).to be == "this should fail"
end
```

Please note that this test *should not* repeat the test of the previous case (that the message is called). Each test should test only one thing.

Comment: Thanks. So I can check if a method is called within the initialize method but can't find what is has returned. Without explicitly calling it that is..?

Comment: As far as _unit test_ is concerned - it shouldn't _matter_ what it actually returns when you are testing if it is called, just like it shouldn't matter _if_ it is called anywhere when you test _what_ it returns.